# How can I access all the objects of an NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary, with six objects, and the keys a, b, c... etc. What I am doing is removing three objects by their keys, and I don't know what objects are going to be removed, as they are determined by user input, so I could be left with a, d, and e. If this was an array, I could just access the ones left over by using objectAtIndex, but I don't know how I can get at these three leftover objects in a dictionary.

This may seem sort of confusing to see what I want to do here, but I want those leftover objects with keys a, d, and e, for instance, but I won't know their keys, so I need another way of accessing them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`-[NSDictionary allValues]` will get you all the values. Or Martin's suggestion if you want all the keys.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use the `allKeys` method on your dictionary, which returns an `NSArray *`.